# SharePoint 2013 - Where is the WebPartPage's StatusBar?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, webpartpage

In a WikiEditPage after editing something, the page shows the apropriate controls to remind that the page current version is not yet visible to other people and can be published.
[image]

So far so good.

My problem is that I'm unable to make a WebPartPage behave the same way.

Although the WebPartPage has unpublished versions, it still doe not show the StatusBar or any other control that warns the user that the page needs to be published.
[image]

What are the alternatives to make a WebPartPage display the relevant controls (StatusBar, Publish Ribon) when a newer version awaits to be published?

Thks in advance,

Alberto

Comment: Originaly posted on http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2eb84c85-e247-40eb-bde7-5c5aea12bd20/where-is-the-webpartpages-statusbar

Comment: does anyone have a clue?